# How to add item to immutable array in React setState in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutability

I want to use an immutable array to handle the state. And add an item to this list.

```js
interface MainState {
  list: readonly []; // define immutable array
}

const Component: React.FC = () => {
  // by default use the immutable array with type
  const [classes, setClasses] = useState({ list: [] } as MainState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      data.forEach((thing) => {
        setClasses(prevState => {
          //
          // Call signature return types '{ list: never[]; }' and 'MainState' are incompatible.
          // The types of 'list.length' are incompatible between these types.
          // Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'.  TS2345
          //
          const list = prevState.list.concat(thing);
          return { list };
        });
      });
    }
  });
// ...

}
```

I though using concat would work, since it [returns a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc you provided:

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more **arrays**

So you need to pass array, not element to this function, I suppose this will work:

```
const list = prevState.list.concat([thing]);
```

Also I see your code is iterating through new array and pass elements one by one, why don't you concat the whole array?

```
    if (data) {
        setClasses(prevState => {
          const list = prevState.list.concat(data);
          // or list = [...prevState.list, ...data];
          return { list };
        });
    }
```

Also I think you missed type of array in you `MainState`, at least update it with `any` type, here is full example for `number` type:

```
interface MainState {
  list: readonly number[];
}

const data = [1, 2, 3]

const Component: React.FC = () => {

  const [classes, setClasses] = useState({ list: [] } as MainState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setClasses(prevState => ({ list: [...prevState.list, ...data]}));
    }
  });

  return <div>{classes}</div>
}
```

Comment: Receive on the `return { list };` the message: `Type 'never[]' is not assignable tot type 'readonly[]'. Types of property 'length' are incompatible. Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'.`

Comment: Updated answer, there was no type of array in your state definition

Answer (score 4):

The easiest, most acceptable way of doing so:

```
const list = [...prevState.list, thing];
```

Comment: I see. I am stil receiving the following error: `Argument of type '(prevState: MainState) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<MainState>. Type '(prevState:MainState) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: MainState) => MainState'. Property 'list' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type MainState`

Comment: Then this will solve part of the problem: `setClasses((prevState): MainState => ({ list: [...prevState.list, CLASS] }));`. But then on the list in the return of the arrow function I am again receiving the `Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'`.